# How to define the style of the selected element on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please tell me how to define the style and change it for the selected html-text?

```
var selection = window.getSelection(),range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
var selectionContents = range.extractContents();
```

But further it is not known how to act

Comment: `::selection { color: orange; }`?

Comment: How you do this would depend on what styling you're looking to apply to the selection

Comment: Thank. Is it possible to check for the presence of a style? For example, if the color is already orange, then do not apply the style.